# Observable iteration complete event

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I'm subscribing to a **BehaviorSubject** `routes$` that emits an array of directions

e.g. `['left', 'top', 'left']`

Then I want to log each element of this array with 200ms delay, now after all element have been logged, I want to log `route finished`.

I tried the complete event `()=>{}` and `finally()` operator but they both don't fire since `routes$` is still alive and might emits new directions.

```
/** Stream recent directions */
this.route$.switchMap(() => {
  return Observable
    .interval(200)
    .timeInterval()
    .take(this.route$.getValue().length)
}).subscribe(
  (v) => {
    if (v.value === this.route$.getValue().length) return;
    let i = v.value;
    this.moveStep(this.route$.getValue()[i]);
  }
);
```

Currently I'm using this workaround

```
.subscribe(
  (v) => {
    if (v.value === this.route$.getValue().length) return;
    let i = v.value;
    this.moveStep(this.route$.getValue()[i]);

    /** Check if it is the last iteration */
    if(i + 1 === this.route$.getValue().length){
      console.log('route finished');
      this.state = PlayerState.Idle;
    }
  }
);
```

Is there a native way to achieve this in observable?

Comment: Could you rewrite this for clarity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do you want to emit a value when the array passed to the BehaviorSubject has been completely iterated and you want to get just the last value.

Try to avoid using `.getValue()` directly from inside the Observable chain because the content of `.getValue()` is something you should be working with in the chain already.

```
var routes$ = new BehaviorSubject(['default']);

routes$.switchMap((arr) => {
    return Observable.interval(200)
        .take(arr.length)
        .map(i => arr[i])
        .timeInterval()
        .do(null, null, () => console.log('Complete'));
}).subscribe(value => {
    console.log(value);
});

routes$.next(['left', 'top', 'left']);

setTimeout(() => {
    routes$.next(['top', 'right', 'down']);
}, 1000);
```

This prints to console:

```
TimeInterval { value: 'left', interval: 208 }
TimeInterval { value: 'top', interval: 241 }
TimeInterval { value: 'left', interval: 207 }
Complete
TimeInterval { value: 'top', interval: 204 }
TimeInterval { value: 'right', interval: 200 }
TimeInterval { value: 'down', interval: 205 }
Complete
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/muxasa/5/edit?js,console

Notice that the `['default']` is never reemitted because `switchMap()` receives a new array when calling `routes$.next(['left', 'top', 'left']);`

Comment: I want to log each element in 200ms delay not only the last, however I want to fire an action when those elements are logged. (after it iterates over the array). your jsbin logs only the last value

Comment: `.do` worked, but now all elements are being logged at once, can I keep 200ms delay between them?

Comment: @MurhafSousli You can `do()` but question is where you want to be notified that the array was completely iterated. You don't want to receive it in `routes$.switchMap(...).subscribe()` because this would make the subscribed automatically unsubscribe(). Otherwise I'd recommend restructure your code and

Comment: @MurhafSousli Btw, with `map()` and `take()` you can still avoid using `.getValue()` in the subscriber.

Answer (score 1):

If your Observable is not completed yet you can use `debounce()` to wait for a certain amount of time before doing something. Other options would be to `buffer` your values by time/amount and then after emitting the buffer do something.